# partial sort a vector with lambda predicate

Tags: c++, sorting

I would like to partial sort this vector with a predicate as such

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> vp;

        std::partial_sort(vp.begin(), vp.begin()+10, [](const std::pair<std::string,int> &left, const std::pair<std::string,int> &right)
        {
            return left.second > right.second;
        });
```

However I get the error

```
 no matching function for call to ‘partial_sort(std::vector<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, int> >::iterator, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, int>*, ....
```

The above works fine for std::sort and not for `partial_sort` any suggestions ?

Comment: Care to provde the `...`? Does it list candidate functions considered and reasons why they were not applicable?

Comment: `partial_sort` requires three iterators? (I only see two.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at some [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort), you will find that `std::partial_sort` requires 3 iterators, not 2: start, middle and end. It will re-arrange the range so that the range `[start, middle)` is sorted, and contains the smallest elements from the range `[start, end)`.

Depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve, you need to provide an appropriate 3rd iterator. If you're trying to find the 10 smallest elements, just do this:

```
std::partial_sort(vp.begin(), vp.begin()+10, vp.end(), /*lambda as before*/);
```